# codeship stuck using old image of codeship/google-cloud-deployment

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, codeship

I've been updating one of our projects that is built and deployed using codeship pro. We use `codeship/google-cloud-deployment` docker image to deploy google cloud functions. I need features that are only available in a recent version of the gcloud sdk, but **codeship always uses an old version the sdk and seems stuck fetching a cached version of the image**.

#### codeship-services.yml

```
googlecloudproductiondeployment:
  image: codeship/google-cloud-deployment
  encrypted_env_file: deploy/deploy-production.env.encrypted
  cached: false
  volumes:
    - ./:/deploy
```

#### codeship-steps.yml

```
- name: Deploy CF to prod
  tag: ^deploy-production$
  service: googlecloudproductiondeployment
  command: /deploy/deploy/google-deploy-cf.sh
```

#### deploy/google-deploy-cf.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -e

PROJECT=my-project
FUNCTION_NAME=my-function
SOURCE_REPO=my-repo

# Authenticate on google SDK
codeship_google authenticate

# Re-deploy the CF
gcloud version
gcloud beta functions deploy $FUNCTION_NAME --region europe-west1 --runtime nodejs8 --env-vars-file /deploy/deploy/cf-env.production.yaml --trigger-http --source https://source.developers.google.com/projects/my-project/repos/${PROJECT}/fixed-aliases/${CI_BRANCH} --memory 128MB --entry-point run --timeout 540s
```

#### Output observed in codeship:

```
googlecloudproductiondeployment build/pull started
googlecloudproductiondeployment build/pull finished successfully
googlecloudproductiondeployment Activated service account credentials for: [***@***.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
googlecloudproductiondeployment Google Cloud SDK 204.0.0
googlecloudproductiondeployment alpha 2017.09.15
googlecloudproductiondeployment beta 2017.09.15
googlecloudproductiondeployment bq 2.0.34
googlecloudproductiondeployment core 2018.06.04
googlecloudproductiondeployment gsutil 4.31
googlecloudproductiondeployment kubectl 
googlecloudproductiondeployment deployng
googlecloudproductiondeployment ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) unrecognized arguments: 2018-10-08 07:42:29 googlecloudproductiondeployment  --runtime (did you mean '--timeout'?)
googlecloudproductiondeployment  nodejs8
googlecloudproductiondeployment  --env-vars-file
googlecloudproductiondeployment  /deploy/deploy/cf-env.production.yaml
```

#### Expected output:

I expect to see `Google Cloud SDK 218.0.0`, the version noted in the last commit in [codeship's google-cloud-deployment github repo](https://github.com/codeship-library/google-cloud-utilities).

#### Steps tried:

1. Adding `:latest` to the image in `codeship-services.yml`.
2. Clicking on `Reset Cache` on the project page on codeship.

   - Even after reseting the cache, I always see `Image exists, using cached image` in the logs for my `googlecloudproductiondeployment` service on codeship.
3. Using jet locally, I can fore codeship to pull the latest version by running `docker rmi codeship/google-cloud-deployment` before jet steps. However, I do not have control over the docker cache on codeship.

It seems codehip is stuck using an old version of the `codeship/google-cloud-deployment` image. On docker hub this image has no tags other than `latest`, so I don't know how to force codeship to get a specific version.  Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the trouble.

We've gone ahead and ensured that versions of `codeship/google-cloud-deployment` will remain current.

In general we will be tracking behind the most current Google Cloud SDK by two to three weeks. But this will maintain much closer parity to most recent versions. We can also expedite updates of Google Cloud SDK now as needed.

If you reset your project cache and restart your build, you will note (as of this time of writing) that the Google Cloud SDK is now set to version `219.0.1` for the `codeship/google-cloud-deployment` image.